# Access the properties of a single element of a custom component created with Lit

Tags: vaadin

i have created in vaadin v23 a custom component using lit templates.
Inside this custom component i have created a form for managing files upload.

In particular i have to do these two actions:

1. when an event get fired in the form i have to read a value (A) of an  field
2. With the value read in step 1 i have to compute another value (B) in a js script and update the value property of another  field

How can i reach  fields of my lit custom component in order to read (A) and write (B)?
Using window.customelements.get("my-custom-component") i only read the text code of the component.
Using document.forms.MyForm.nome.value i catch undefined.

Thanks for your advice

Comment: This is the code:

Comment: You'll need to add some code please. I cannot understand your questions.

Comment: import { html, LitElement } from 'lit';

class MyPresignedComponent extends LitElement {

  static get properties() {
    return {
      title: { type: String }
    }
  }
  render() {
    return html`
    <h3>${this.title}</h3>
    <script type="text/javascript" source="/util/utils.js"></script>
    <form name = "formUp" action="">
 <input name="uuid" value="123456">
    <input type='file' id="file" ref="inputFile"  name='file' onChange="funzjs(XXXXX)"/> <br />
    </form>
     `;
  }
}
window.customElements.define('presigned-custom-component', MyPresignedComponent);

Comment: I would pass the value of input element uuid inside che javascript function calling inside onChange Event

Comment: Can you please add your code to your question and format it properly? https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

```
import { html, LitElement } from 'lit';

class MyCustomComponent extends LitElement {
static get properties() {
    return {
      pvalue: { type: String }
    }
  }
  render() {
return html`
 <form action='https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' onsubmit="" name="myForm">
        <input type='text'  name='key' value='${this.pvalue}' />
       <input type='file' id="file" ref="inputFile"  name='file' onChange="putS3Post(file,'XXXXXX'); } return (goOn)"/> <br />
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload object in Amazon S3 bucket' />
  </form>
    `;
  }
}
window.customElements.define('custom-component', MyCustomComponent);
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: The goal is to execute the file upload operation towards S3 bucket directly in client side avoiding to use server memory and other server resources. 
When user chooses the file to upload i intercept onChange event and inside my own js function named putS3Post i need to catch some information (i.e. digest and other information) and i don't know how read the value of the input named key. This input field get populated by an initial value but it can change because of user can change it and before choose tyhe file to upload.

Comment: Thank you! That’s useful. Can you [edit] your answer to include that?

Comment: I have followed what Amazon explains about (Browser-Based Upload using HTTP POST - Using AWS Signature Version 4) see here (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html). I have to add another operation, before user presses submit button, i have to calculate a SHA256 digest and then, rebuild the policy, populate the input text value in order to respect policy rules and succed in the uploading operation.